# Counting records and grouping them by the hour

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to count the records in my table and grouping them by hour, i'm getting results with my query but I want it to return every hour even if there are no records.

My current query is,

```
SELECT nvl(count(*),0) AS transactioncount, trunc(date_modified, 'HH') as TRANSACTIONDATE
FROM TABLE 
WHERE date_modified between to_date('23-JAN-19 07:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('24-Jan-19 06:59:59','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
group by trunc(date_modified, 'HH');
```

This returns a result like this,

```
TRANSACTIONCOUNT    |    TRANSACTIONDATE
      43            |   23-Jan-19 07:00:00
      47            |   23-Jan-19 08:00:00
      156           |   23-Jan-19 14:00:00
      558           |   23-Jan-19 15:00:00
```

What I want is for it to return every hour between my 2 dates so,

```
TRANSACTIONCOUNT    |    TRANSACTIONDATE
      43            |   23-Jan-19 07:00:00
      47            |   23-Jan-19 08:00:00
      0             |   23-Jan-19 09:00:00
      0             |   23-Jan-19 10:00:00
      0             |   23-Jan-19 11:00:00
      0             |   23-Jan-19 12:00:00
      0             |   23-Jan-19 13:00:00
      156           |   23-Jan-19 14:00:00
      558           |   23-Jan-19 15:00:00
  --......
      0             |   24-Jan-19 00:00:00
      0             |   24-Jan-19 01:00:00
      0             |   24-Jan-19 02:00:00
  --and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the following with `CONNECT BY level` logic :

```
SELECT sum(transactioncount) as transactioncount, transactiondate 
  FROM
  (
   with "TABLE"(date_modified) as
   (
     SELECT timestamp'2019-01-23 08:00:00' FROM dual union all
     SELECT timestamp'2019-01-23 08:30:00' FROM dual union all
     SELECT timestamp'2019-01-23 09:00:00' FROM dual union all
     SELECT timestamp'2019-01-24 05:01:00' FROM dual   
   )   
  SELECT nvl(count(*),0) AS transactioncount, trunc(date_modified, 'hh24') as transactiondate
    FROM "TABLE" t 
   GROUP BY trunc(date_modified, 'HH24')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, timestamp'2019-01-23 07:00:00' + ( level - 1 )/24
    FROM dual    
 CONNECT BY level <=  24 * extract( day  from 
                            timestamp'2019-01-24 06:59:59'-
                            timestamp'2019-01-23 07:00:00') +
                           extract( hour from 
                            timestamp'2019-01-24 06:59:59'-
                            timestamp'2019-01-23 07:00:00') + 1      
)    
 GROUP BY transactiondate
 ORDER BY transactiondate
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/GOTMU26957)</kbd>

Comment: mmm... it worked but it's not showing '23-JAN-19 07:00:00' when there is no data for that hour.

Comment: @crimson589 excuse me, the trick `( level - 1 )` was missing. In that way the starting time was excluded due to missing value of zero for level.

Comment: Sorry, only got to try it out today. I changed it to (level - 1) but now I'm losing 6AM of January 24 if there's no data on that date.

Comment: @crimson589 you're right. I realised that didn't consider the "day" part, and now added. (+1) at the last of the difference comes from the logic "there exist four trees between the 2nd and 5th, boundries included, calculated as 5 - 2 + 1 = 4 `including the substracted, i.e. 2nd one` "

Answer (score 2):

To fill the *holes* in the transaction hours you create first a complete table of hours.

You may use [*Recursive Subquery Factoring*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) to do it

```
WITH hour_table(TRANSACTIONDATE) AS (
   SELECT to_date('23-JAN-19 07:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') /* init hour here */
     FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
   SELECT TRANSACTIONDATE + 1/24
     FROM hour_table
    WHERE TRANSACTIONDATE + 1/24 < to_date('24-JAN-19 06:59:59','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') /* limit here */
)
select * from hour_table;

TRANSACTIONDATE   
-------------------
23.01.2019 07:00:00 
23.01.2019 08:00:00 
... 
24.01.2019 05:00:00 
24.01.2019 06:00:00
```

Note that you use the staring and ending date in this query, the starting date must be exact an hour.

Next step is as simple as to *outer join* this hour table to your aggregation and set the default value for the missing hours with `NVL`.

```
with hour_table(TRANSACTIONDATE) AS (
   SELECT to_date('23-JAN-19 07:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') /* init hour here */
     FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
   SELECT TRANSACTIONDATE + 1/24
     FROM hour_table
    WHERE TRANSACTIONDATE + 1/24 < to_date('24-JAN-19 06:59:59','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') /* limit */
),
agg as (   
   SELECT nvl(count(*),0) AS transactioncount, trunc(date_modified, 'HH') as TRANSACTIONDATE
   FROM "TABLE" 
   WHERE date_modified between to_date('23-JAN-19 07:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('24-Jan-19 06:59:59','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
   group by trunc(date_modified, 'HH')
)
select t.TRANSACTIONDATE, nvl(transactioncount,0) transactioncount
from hour_table t
left outer join agg a
on t.TRANSACTIONDATE = a.TRANSACTIONDATE
order by 1;
```